# Will refrigerator freezing garlic in the pot for a few hours create the necessary cold time required?

Tags: garlic

My garlic heads that were dying already didn't turn out too well, and my elephant garlic isn't turning out yet, should I throw the pots in the freezer for a few hours in order to simulate to the garlic it's time to grow?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just pull it all out and eat it? It sounds too late to try and grow garlic from mid summer.

From what I can tell you're trying to grow store bought elephant garlic but there's a problem. That problem isn't stated. If it hasn't sprouted after being in the ground with your heat, it's probably never going to now.

If you are starting with good garlic seed, and you want vernalization to occur, then:

> If you miss the window for fall planting, ensure that your seed garlic gets 40 days at or below 40°F before planting, or the lack of vernalization will mean the bulbs will not differentiate (divide into separate cloves).

Will your parents tolerate pots of dirt in the fridge for 1.3 months?

http://www.growingformarket.com/articles/how-and-when-to-plant-garlic

Comment: some is doing well, and some is doing bad. the elephant garlic I planted in pots has roots, but no shoot.